# Lua: Values zeroed when passed back to scene with button transition

Tags: button, timer, lua, return-value, scene

I am new to programming - less than a year.
I am using two types of scene transition: one with a button and one with a timer. 
I can pass values back to a scene with a timer but I cannot pass values (in this example x) back to a scene with a button. The variable becomes ineffective and the value simply vanishes, including from the simulator output. X ceases to increment or play any part. How do I overcome this?

-- main.lua

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

    x = 0

local composer = require "composer"

composer.gotoScene("test1")
```

-- test1.lua

```
local composer = require "composer"
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create(event)
    local screenGroup = self.view

    local widget = require "widget"
    local test2Btn
    local function onTest2BtnRelease()
            composer.gotoScene("test2")
            return true 
    end

            test2Btn = widget.newButton{
            defaultFile = "images/pic1.png",
            width= 480, height= 320,
            onRelease = onTest2BtnRelease 
    }

    screenGroup:insert(test2Btn)
end

    x = x + 1
    print("test1 x = "..x)  

scene:addEventListener("create", scene)

return scene
```

-- test2.lua

```
local composer = require "composer"
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create(event)
    local screenGroup = self.view

    local widget = require "widget"
    local test3Btn
    local function onTest3BtnRelease()
            composer.gotoScene("test3")
            return true 
    end

            test3Btn = widget.newButton{
            defaultFile = "images/pic2.png",
            width= 480, height= 320,
            onRelease = onTest3BtnRelease 
    }

    screenGroup:insert(test3Btn)
end

    x = x + 1
    print("test2 x = "..x)  

scene:addEventListener("create", scene)

return scene
```

-- test3.lua

```
    local composer = require ( "composer")
    local scene = composer.newScene()

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end     

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
        if ( phase == "will") then

           background = display.newImage( "images/pic3.png", 240, 160 )

                    sceneGroup:insert( background )

        elseif ( phase == "did") then                                                                   
              local function showTest4()
                   local options = {
                        effect = "slideLeft",
                        time = 30,
                   }
           composer.gotoScene( "test4", options )
        end

        timer.performWithDelay( 60000/40, showTest4 )
        end 
    end 

                    x = x + 1
                    print("test3 x = "..x)                                                          

    function scene:hide( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
            local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

    return scene
```

-- test4.lua

```
    local composer = require ( "composer")
    local scene = composer.newScene()

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end     

  function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
        if ( phase == "will") then
            background = display.newImage( "images/pic4.png", 240, 160 )
            sceneGroup:insert( background )

            elseif ( phase == "did") then                                                                   
                 local function showTest1()
                     local options = {
                         effect = "slideLeft",
                         time = 30,
                     }
            composer.gotoScene( "test1", options )
            end

    timer.performWithDelay( 60000/40, showTest1 )
    end

  end 

                    x = x + 1
                    print("test4 x = "..x)                                                          

    function scene:hide( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
            local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

    return scene
```

Comment: Please try to specify a bit more detailed which calls in your code don't work as you expect. Make a list of a) your actions, b) program output and comment where it differs from your expectations

Comment: Hello Ctx, 
In my example x is set at zero in main.lua.
The scenes move from one to another either via a button or a timer. 
In this sequence of scenes x is incremented each time:
In test1.lua (transition to next scene via button) x = 1. 
In test2.lua (transition to next scene via button) x = 2. 
In test3.lua (transition to next scene via timer) x = 3. 
In test4.lua (transition to next scene via timer) x = 4. 
But on returning to test1.lua (from test4.lua) x = 1 again. I need x = 5. The output simulator does not print out the new value of x.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this really output: "test1 x = 1" in the second transition to test1? exactly as in the first transition?

Comment: After digging deeper into this, I cannot believe that the print-command in test1.lua is executed a second time, since the file is require()d only once by the framework and reused after this. Please be more accurate in the description of the behaviour, how exactly do you see that x=1 after composer.gotoScene("test1", options) in test4.lua

Comment: The app is essentially a slide-show, repeating a set sequence of scenes, all with different data. 
After each time through the sequence it returns to the start – in the example this is test1.lua. In order to work its way through the database (not shown in the example) the variable calling the data has to increment each and every time.
This works fine when the scene change is triggered by (1) a timer in a timer-to-timer scene change, (2) a button in a button-to-button scene change, (3) a timer in a timer-to-button to timer scene change, but not by (4) a timer in a timer-to-button scene change.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you this way... The code outside the event handlers (namely x = x + 1, print ...) is only executed once when the scene is _first_ loaded. So it is not suitable to demonstrate what you mean at all. You will not see "test1 x = "..x a second time

Comment: Is there any way round this apart from creating dozens of new test1 scenes? Is it acceptable/normal to create so many? I thought it would not be very elegant programming to do so. There would be sixty of them in the finished app. Thanks, by the way, for your help with this.

Comment: I can't believe that Lua is incapable of this simple incrementation. If it is then it's a big failing. Please someone give me a hand here - with a rep of 30 I am facing a brick wall. Thanks.